# sqlite failed couldn't read row 0 col -1 from cursorwindow from cursor in alarm service

Tags: android, sqlite, service, cursor

i'm trying to develop a service that continuously check the sqlite database at every 2 min for the match record. I found the following 2 errors:

error in log :

> couldn't read row 0 col  -1 from cursorwindow

my java files are mentioned below

```
 **myseervice.java** 



         package com.blundell.tut.ui.phone;

        import java.io.BufferedReader;
        import java.io.FileInputStream;
        import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
        import java.io.IOException;
        import java.io.InputStream;
        import java.io.InputStreamReader;
        import java.util.ArrayList;
        import java.util.Calendar;
        import java.util.HashMap;

        import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
        import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
        import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
        import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
        import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
        import org.apache.http.client.entity.UrlEncodedFormEntity;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
        import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
        import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
        import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

        import com.blundell.tut.R;

        import android.app.AlertDialog;
        import android.app.Notification;
        import android.app.NotificationManager;
        import android.app.PendingIntent;
        import android.app.Service;
        import android.content.Context;
        import android.content.Intent;
        import android.database.Cursor;
        import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
        import android.os.IBinder;
        import android.util.Log;
        import android.widget.Toast;

        public class MyService extends Service {
            /*---String result;
            String oid1,operatorid1;*/
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(this);
            public String tableName = db.TABLE_CONTACTS;

            public String task_name = db.KEY_TASK;
            public String dt = db.KEY_DATETIME;
            String tname, dt1;
            NotificationManager nm;
            static final int uniqueID = 1394885;
            ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler;
            SQLiteDatabase dbobject;
            Cursor c;
            Context context, ctx1;

            // flag for Internet connection status
            // -- Boolean isInternetPresent = false;

            // Connection detector class
            // ---- ConnectionDetector cd;
            @Override
            public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
                return null;
            }

            @Override
            public void onCreate() {
                super.onCreate();
            }

            @Override
            public void onDestroy() {
                super.onDestroy();
            }

            @Override
            public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
                final Calendar c1 = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = c1.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minutes = c1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
                int day = c1.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
                int month = c1.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                int year1 = c1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                String combine = String.valueOf(day).trim() + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(month + 1).trim() + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(year1).trim() + String.valueOf(hour) + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(minutes);
                String combine2 = String.valueOf(day).trim() + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(month + 1).trim() + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(year1).trim() + String.valueOf(hour) + ":"
                        + String.valueOf(minutes - 1);

                Log.w("trace", "date   " + combine);
                Log.w("trace", "date   " + combine2);

                // dbobject=this.openOrCreateDatabase("engdb.db",SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY,null);
                MainActivity act = new MainActivity();

                dbobject = act.getInstance().openOrCreateDatabase("contactsManager",
                        SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                // setDatabase(dbobject);

                // String create_table
                // ="create table if not exists contact(_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                // +
                // " Day text null, Month text null,Year text null, Hour text null, Minutes text )";
                // dbobject.execSQL(create_table);

                String q = "SELECT task_name FROM contacts WHERE date_time='" + combine
                        + "'";

                c = dbobject.rawQuery(q, null);
                System.out.print("totle record" + c.getCount());

                if (c.moveToFirst()) {
                    for (int i = 0; i <= c.getCount(); i++) {
                        tname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task_name"));
                        dt1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_time"));
                        c.moveToNext();
                    }
                    c.close();
                }

                // if (c!=null) {
                // do {
                // // Contact contact = new Contact();
                // /*
                // * int id1=Integer.parseInt(c.getString(0)); String tname =
                // * c.getString(1); String dt1 = c.getString(2);
                // */// Adding contact to list
                // // contactList.add(contact);
                // tname = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task_name"));
                // dt1 = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_time"));
                //
                // } while (c.moveToNext());
                // }
                /*
                 * c.moveToNext();
                 * 
                 * String tname =c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task_name")); String dt1
                 * = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_time"));
                 */
                // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Service method is called",
                // 1000).show();
                Log.w("trace", "alarm has been fired " + c.getCount() + "    " + tname
                        + "   " + dt1);
                // c.close();
                // ---- creating connection detector class instance
                // cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());

                // get Internet status
                // ---- isInternetPresent = cd.isConnectingToInternet();
                // check for Internet status
                /*
                 * if (isInternetPresent) {
                 */nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.cancel(uniqueID);

                /*
                 * //open sqlite database here... localdatabase =
                 * context.openOrCreateDatabase("engdb.db",
                 * SQLiteDatabase.CREATE_IF_NECESSARY, null);
                 * setDatabase(localdatabase); String create_table =
                 * "create table if not exists contact((_id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                 * + " Day text not null, Month text not null,Year text)";
                 * localdatabase.execSQL(create_table);
                 */

                /*
                 * FileInputStream fin1; try { fin1 =openFileInput("op_id.txt");
                 * InputStreamReader isr1 = new InputStreamReader(fin1); char[]
                 * inputBuffer1 = new char[100]; String s1=""; int charRead1;
                 * while((charRead1 = isr1.read(inputBuffer1))>0) { String readString1
                 * =String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer1,0,charRead1); s1 += readString1;
                 * inputBuffer1=new char[100]; oid1=(s1); operatorid1=oid1;
                 * //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "in service."+operatorid1,
                 * 1000).show(); } }
                 */
                /*
                 * catch (FileNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); } catch
                 * (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */
                /*
                 * try { ArrayList<NameValuePair> myForm=new
                 * ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1); myForm.add(new
                 * BasicNameValuePair("oid",operatorid1)); MyConnection mycon = new
                 * MyConnection(); String url= mycon.myurl(); HttpClient client = new
                 * DefaultHttpClient(); //ticket_check_service.php HttpPost postdata =
                 * new HttpPost(url+"op_ticket_check_service.php"); responseHandler =
                 * new BasicResponseHandler(); postdata.setEntity(new
                 * UrlEncodedFormEntity(myForm)); result = client.execute(postdata,
                 * responseHandler); } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                 * e.printStackTrace(); } catch (IOException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
                 */

                /*
                 * if(result.equals("0")==true) {
                 * //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Sorry try again"+result,
                 * 1500).show(); } else { // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                 * " Welcome Client "+result, 1500).show(); String str1 =
                 * result.substring(result.indexOf("T"),result.indexOf("T")+7); Intent
                 * myintent= new Intent(this,Ticket_List.class);
                 * myintent.putExtra("notift", "ticketnotif");
                 * myintent.putExtra("ticketid", str1); PendingIntent
                 * pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext( ),0, myintent,
                 * 0); String body="Client Response for above Ticket id."; String title
                 * =result; Notification n= new
                 * Notification(R.drawable.notif_logo,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
                 * n.setLatestEventInfo(this,title, body,pi); n.defaults =
                 * Notification.DEFAULT_ALL; nm.notify(uniqueID,n);
                 * 
                 * }
                 */

                /*
                 * 
                 * Intent myintent= new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class); PendingIntent
                 * pi=PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext( ),0, myintent,
                 * 0); String body="Client Response for above Ticket id."; String title
                 * ="result"; Notification n= new
                 * Notification(R.drawable.nfm,body,System.currentTimeMillis());
                 * n.setLatestEventInfo(this,title, body,pi); n.defaults =
                 * Notification.DEFAULT_ALL; nm.notify(uniqueID,n);
                 * 
                 * super.onStart(intent, startId);
                 */

            }

            public void setDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db) {
                this.dbobject = db;
            }
        }// end of IF condition
        // end of start method






        ****database handler.java****



     package com.blundell.tut.ui.phone;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import android.content.ContentValues;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // All Static variables
        // Database Version
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        // Database Name
        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "contactsManager";

        // Contacts table name
        public static final String TABLE_CONTACTS = "contacts";

        // Contacts Table Columns names
        public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        public static final String KEY_TASK = "task_name";
        public static final String KEY_DATETIME = "date_time";
        Context ctx;
        public List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();

        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            ctx = context;
        }

        // Creating Tables
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                    + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_TASK + " TEXT,"
                    + KEY_DATETIME + " TEXT" + ")";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
        }

        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACTS);

            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
        }

        /**
         * All CRUD(Create, Read, Update, Delete) Operations
         */

        // Adding new contact
        public void addContact(Contact contact) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_TASK, contact.getName()); // Contact Name
            values.put(KEY_DATETIME, contact.getPhoneNumber()); // Contact Phone

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_CONTACTS, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }

        // Getting single contact
        Contact getContact(int id) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
                    KEY_TASK, KEY_DATETIME }, KEY_ID + "=?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null)
                cursor.moveToFirst();

            Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
                    cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));
            // return contact
            return contact;
        }

        // Getting All Contacts
        public List<Contact> getAllContacts() {
            try {
                List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
                contactList.clear();
                System.out.print("clear array list :");

                // Select All Query
                String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;

                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
                Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                // looping through all rows and adding to list
                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    do {
                        Contact contact = new Contact();
                        contact.setID(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)));
                        contact.setName(cursor.getString(1));
                        contact.setPhoneNumber(cursor.getString(2));
                        // Adding contact to list
                        contactList.add(contact);
                    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
                }

                cursor.close();
                // return contact list
                return contactList;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
                Log.e("all_contact", "" + e);
            }
            List<Contact> contactList = new ArrayList<Contact>();
            return contactList;
        }

        // Updating single contact
        public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_TASK, contact.getName());
            values.put(KEY_DATETIME, contact.getPhoneNumber());

            // updating row
            return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
        }

        // Deleting single contact
        public void deleteContact(Contact contact) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            db.delete(TABLE_CONTACTS, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
            db.close();
        }

        // Getting numbers of contacts Count
        public int getContactsCount() {
            String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_CONTACTS;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
            cursor.close();

            // return count
            return cursor.getCount();
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want to read data from column which doesn't exists. Column -1 means that specified column was not found in database.

For sure in this level it's not problem from service, but with your database configuration.

Comment: hay thanx  buddy :but actually  data is displayd in sqlite data base and also in log  first time .i wnn know wht the meaning of col-1 ..is there my database structure .??

Comment: From my experience: you should have columns name, like i.e. "Users". Then for your sqllite instance (i.e. SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();) you must get cursor using query db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM Users", null). Your error could appears when you go trought the cursor, i.e.: cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("Users"));. If column is not found getColumnIndex retuns -1. So you should debug your select in sqllite adapter.

Answer (score 1):

This seams wrong:

```
        cursor.close();

        // return count
        return cursor.getCount();
```

You must not refer a object after closing/disposing/unloading it.

Answer (score 0):

The relevant parts of your code:

```
q = "SELECT task_name FROM contacts WHERE date_time='" + combine + "'";
...
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("task_name"));
c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("date_time"));
```

`getColumnIndex` returns `-1` if it cannot find the column name.

The query returns only a single column, `task_name`.
If you wanted to read the `date_time` values, you would have to tell the database to `SELECT` them, too. (But you already *know* the value, so you don't actually need to read it.)

Comment: Then it would return all columns.

Comment: is is compulsory that table have the first column named _id ?? i mean that we can take id field as well !!is there any convention ??